# Flipper's(Debugging Platform) Logs data is collapsed by default

Tags: json, react-native, debugging, flipper

I am using `Flipper's`(Debugging Platform) for `react-native` app debugging purpose. when I logged a `JSON` object `Flipper` is showing the `JSON` by collapsing the entire object by default. `JSON` object is too large and contains lot of nested objects. Hence it is being very difficult to see the data since JSON object is collapsible by default.

How JSON object looks like in `Flipper`

[image]

In the above image we can see that top level object and all nested objects are collapsible.

Can we have the control over the `JSON` object to have collapsible or non-collapsible as per our choice?

Comment: Hi @Mighty how can we get this?

Comment: @CODEforDREAM Unfortunately I have not figured it out

Comment: Hi @Migth how can i get this UI of json in flipper, default flipper so hard to debug the code